# MySql - Changing expire_logs_days without restarting the server

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I'm using MySql 5.5.
Is it possible to change `expire_logs_days` and have the changes take effect without restarting the server?

Comment: `SET expire_log_days = 1`?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days

Answer (score 20):

In MySQL 5.6, you would want to show what your expire_logs_days is set to first. Then confirm that the master doesnt need to keep these logs more than `x` amount of days. Word of caution, having binary logs that low in days can be a big risk.

Set globally as:

```
mysql> show variables like 'expire_logs_days';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| expire_logs_days | 5     |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> set global expire_logs_days=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.62 sec)
```

```
mysql> show variables like 'expire_logs_days';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| expire_logs_days | 1     |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then dont forget to update the my.cnf file if you want this setting to remain or survive a service restart:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/my.cnf
    expire_logs_days               = 1
```

Then flush the current log and to have the binary log statement to take effect on all the logs older than 1 day, in your case:

```
mysql> flush binary logs;
```

Comment: Does that mean this is not applicable to 5.5 ? As OP asked for MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 13):

thanks @dezso

here is how I changed it: `SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 4;`

Answer (score 2):

Since MySQL 8 it's `binlog_expire_logs_seconds`, e.g. to set to 3 days one would do:

```
SET GLOBAL binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 259200;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql (community) Version 8.0.17-1.sles12  -  OpenSUSE tumbleweed 2019.10.02

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 4;
ERROR 3683 (HY000): The option expire_logs_days and binlog_expire_logs_seconds
cannot be used together. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds to set the expire
time (expire_logs_days is deprecated)
```

..